# some peoples are says class is collection of objects and others says class is instance of an object which oop definition is correct?

Tags: class, oop, object, collections, blueprint

First of all! Iam new to programming,
In a blog i saw this two definitions . but iam confused .
It says

> Class is a instance of an object

and another says

> Class is a collection of objecs

Which definition is correct? How?
If both definitions are true? How?
Thank you

Comment: Neither. The answer is neither.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, a class is the mold with which you can create an objet. With one class, you create many objects of the same type.

An object is thus an instance of a class (but not the other way around).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

An object is an instance of a class. An object can be instantiated in other classes. A class is definitely **not** a collection of objects. However, other objects can be created or instantiated inside of a class.

Comment: A class isn't an object.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. That is true, an object is a class, but a class is not an object.

Comment: Actually it might depend on the programming language. In JavaScript, classes are syntactic sugar over constructor functions, which in turn are objects...

Answer (score 0):

A class is a blueprint to build a specific type of object. Every object is built from a class.

An instance is a specific object built from a specific class. It is assigned to a reference variable that is used to access the instance's properties and methods. The process of making a new instance is called instantiation and is typically done using the new keyword.

A collection of objects is just that, a collection. There are many data structures designed to hold a collection of object, such as arrays, lists, etc.